# Thread Getting Interrupted in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, excel, thread-safety

I am running code in a thread upon opening an Excel workbook that takes some time to execute.  If I attempt to close the workbook while the thread is still executing, giving me the standard prompt to Save or cancel, my thread is interrupted (not sure if "interrupted" is technically the right term) when I click Cancel.  More generally, it seems that UI interactions/updates cause the thread to be interrupted.

Is there a way to either 1) prevent the thread from being halted by a UI update/user interaction, or 2) allow the thread to resume after being interrupted?

Nothing fancy about the code:

```
Private Shared Sub Test()
    Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf DoSomethingThatTakesAWhile)
    t.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: What does "interrupted" mean? What _exactly_ happens? What do you see in the debugger?

Comment: Are you just getting an exception in the thread?

Comment: Hi Ryan, this doesn't answer your specific question but, I believe you can set the visibility of your Excel application object to false, so that users can't interact with it.  Depending on what your application is doing you may be able to do the long running task (while indicating progress somehow) and then display Excel when it's finished, for example.

Comment: @appclay: If the user happens to be using Excel, that will really bother him.

Comment: can you provide the code for DoSomethingThatTakesAWhile(). When are you opening the excel file from the code?

Comment: "Interrupted" in the context I have used it simply means that the thread does not appear to complete execution in some cases. There is no exception thrown if I hit Esc to exit the workbook close dialog before the thread completes execution.  However, if I leave the Save/Cancel dialog open for a while (presumably long enough to allow the thread to execute) and then hit Esc, I get a regular exception whose Message is: "The message filter indicated that the application is busy. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLAYER))"...

Comment: ...In the latter case, it appears that the thread completes and when it does, it finds that the UI has changed (there is a workbook close dialog open) and throws an error.  Setting visibility to false isn't an option.  As for the code, just imagine a long loop in a Try/Catch block (the code actually inspects the formatting properties of all cells in the workbook, without changing/selecting them).  Too complex to post here, and that's not where the issue is, anyway.

Comment: Why is setting visibility not an option?  I have a program that opens a new instance of Excel (with visible = False) and I am able to work on other spreadsheets as it does its magic.  Then it sets its visibility to true so the user can interact.  Regardless of what I do, I don't mess up that thread.  @SLaks - appclay is correct, as long as it is another instance of Excel; it does not make any other Excel instance disappear.

Comment: @APrough: The point of putting the code in a separate thread is so that the user can interact with Excel while the code executes.  Making the app invisible would obviate the need for threading.

Comment: @Geek on Demand:  The file is being opened manually from the Start menu after Excel is already open (a WorkbookOpen event triggers my thread to run in the background).

Comment: @APrough:  I see what you're saying now, and that approach has merit, but I would like to stick to the current plan.  I'll take that into consideration as a last resort, but want to stick with a single instance of Excel for now to support additional functionality later (e.g. thread progress displayed in StatusBar, etc.).

Comment: Any other thoughts?  In reading more, it seems that this may be a COM threading issue.  What I've read seems to suggest setting ApartmentState = STA for COM threading, but I haven't figured out how to change it from MTA using TrySetApartmentState.  To be more specific about the error message I quoted above, it appears as a COMException.

Comment: Here's a clue as to what's happening.  Still no resolution, though.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8sesy69e(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I made a bunch of progress on this, but ultimately could not get this to work using my original approach.  So, I switched to .Net Framework 4.0 and used Tasks (System.Threading.Tasks namespace) to handle the job.  Tasks worked beautifully and intuitively, and removed much of the complexity around thread management.